# Pin or lock version of a dependency gem installed as part of bundle install

Tags: ruby, bundler, pinning

I'm trying to work around [a bug in the **ffi** Gem on Windows](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/440).  I need to run `bundle install` on [some project that I pulled from the internet](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy).  The problem is that `bundle install` is trying to install version 1.9.9 of **ffi**, which will error out.

Is there some way I can tell `bundle install` to install version 1.9.8 of **ffi**? Perhaps a command line parameter, or an addition to the `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock`?

One possible complication is that [the Gemfile I'm dealing with](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy/blob/develop/Gemfile) does not list **ffi** at all, so it must be pulled in by one of the dependencies' dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicitly list the version of `ffi` you want in your Gemfile. That's what it's for:

```
gem 'ffi', '1.9.8'
```

If your `Gemfile.lock` already has `ffi` locked to version 1.9.9 (which is probably the case for you), you may have to run `bundle update ffi` after adding that to your Gemfile before `bundle install` will work correctly.

Comment: Cool, that worked. The only trick was that I had to explicitly uninstall the broken version `gem uninstall ffi -v 1.9.9` before `bundle install` would work.

Comment: @MichaelKropat Added info on updating locked dependencies. `bundle update ffi` was probably what you were looking for there, but it seems uninstalling the gem worked in your case.